# What is it _|_ in Ruby language?

Tags: ruby, irb

I've seen this thing it smarterer.com tests. I've tested it in irb like this:

```
2.2.0 :019 > puts _|_
13
=> nil 

2.2.0 :020 > c = a.to_s.to_i;c+=1;i=13;puts _|_
false
=> nil
```

So strange behavior. So what this thing is and what should it do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's three tokens. `_`, and `|`, and `_`, and it only works in IRB or other environments where `_` is defined.

This:

```
puts _|_
```

...is identical to this...

```
puts _ | _
```

...which is a simple bitwise OR of the variable `_` with itself.

The only reason I can think of to do this is that it will turn `nil` into `false` in cases where you need a real boolean, not just a falsy value:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil | nil
=> false
```

Otherwise, `a | a` is always going to be `a` for types that support `|`, with the [notable exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319875/what-is-it-in-ruby-language/31319962#comment50629759_31319962) of some built-in types.

Comment: The variable `_` isn't defined in `irb`

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes; `_` is the value of the last expression in IRB. Try it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You don't actually need to *do* anything to define `_`; it's `nil` as soon as you start IRB: http://pastebin.com/YVfSudg7

Comment: @meagar: I was demonstrating that it has value of the last expression :)

Comment: @meagar,@SergioTulentsev Thanks! Never knew!

Comment: If the only reason is to turn nil into false, I think I'd prefer !!_

Comment: *"`a | a` is always going to be `a`"* - not necessarily. Classes can implement `|` in different ways. [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-7C) returns a set union, i.e.  `ary | ary` is equivalent to `ary.uniq`

Comment: @Stefan I was prepared to disregard your comment, thinking "of course you *can* make `|` do whatever you want, but that's hardly here or there". But the point that built-in classes already do this is a very good one.